# my main's function is declared as

Tags: bash, shell, awk

Is the error I get everytime I compile my file, the error references me to line 7, which is where I declare the main() function.

my main's function is declared as

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
does anyone know what's causing this?

any help is greatly appreciated.

line 1-6 is

Comment: It would be more useful if you posted some sample input and expected output rather than have us try to figure out what your sed commands, etc. are doing. Whatever it is you're doing, I'm sure it can be done in one trivial awk command.

Comment: So, the original shell+awk question has now disappeared and been replaced by a totally unrelated C (presumably) question. What a waste of time...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't necessary to make a single-line awk script to embed it into a shell script.  When you use single-quotes, it automatically handles multiple lines.

```
for ARG in "$@"
do
    postcode=`echo "$ARG" | sed -e 's/\(.*\)/\U\1/'`
    areacode=`echo "$postcode" | sed -e 's/.*\(^[A-Z][A-Z]*\).*/\1/' | sed -e 's/\(.*\)/\L\1/'`
    awk  -v pcode="\"""$postcode""\"" '
        BEGIN {FS = ","}
        {if (pcode == $1){ print $1", " $3", " $4 }}
    ' < "$areacode".csv 
done
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you're trying to make it so you only have one shell script, and not one shell script and one awk acript, correct?

You can put the awk program on the command line when you invoke `awk`.  Just put it in single quotes.

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS = ","} {if....}' -v pcode="\"""$postcode""\"" < "$areacode".csv
```

Then you don't have a separate .awk file.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
for ARG in "$@"
do
    postcode=`echo "$ARG" | sed -e 's/\(.*\)/\U\1/'`
    areacode=`echo "$postcode" | sed -e 's/.*\(^[A-Z][A-Z]*\).*/\1/' | sed -e 's/\(.*\)/\L\1/'`
    awk -F, -vOFS=, -v pcode="$postcode" \
      '$1 == pcode {print $1, $3, $4}' < "$areacode".csv
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Untested since you didn't provide any sample input and expected output but it LOOKS like this is what you're trying to do:

```
awk -v args="$@" '
BEGIN {
   FS = ","
   OFS = ", "
   n = split(args,argA)
   for (i=1; i<=n; i++) {
      arg = argA[i]
      match(arg,/[[:alpha:]]+/)
      areacode = substr(arg,RSTART,RLENGTH)
      ARGV[++ARGC] = tolower(areacode) ".csv"
      postcodes[ARGC] = "\"" toupper(arg) "\""
   }
}
FNR == 1 { pcode = postcodes[++argInd] }
$1 == pcode { print $1, $3, $4 }
'
```

If you use GNU awk then you can use ARGIND instead of ++argInd.

Again it's hard to say without some sample input but the above can be made more efficient if you have the same areacodes and/or postcodes repeated in your input. In particular the areacodes files could each be searched just once for all postcodes they could contain.